# Change Validation Error Position

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am using the [MahApps.Metro][1] library for my project.

The Validation Error Popup is blocking the Description of my Texbox since it's on the right side by default. **How can I change it to the left?**

Here's my situation:

[image: captura_de_tela_082615_053528_pm]

And this is the original Form:

[image: captura_de_tela_082615_053554_pm]

So when the window opens, the user can't see there is a field called "Name", just something that can't be blank, but he can't know what he's supposed to type.

I tried a watermark instead, but I didn't like it for this particular application, I rather a Form style, as it is.

---

**EDIT :**

I tried this code in my Resources.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type mahapps:CustomValidationPopup}">        
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Left" />
</Style>
```

But it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you sure you want place on left not right?

Comment: `Bottom` does the same....and the validation popup is supposed to be on top of everything, so I guess space shouldn't be a concern...

Comment: Yeah but what if your window is appearing on extreme right of screen.

Comment: good point...but it isnt...but when I move it to the extreme right, it changes to the left indeed...

Comment: @mFeinstein Which version of MahApps are you using?

Comment: @punker76 1.1.2, the latest stable version.